# Arquivos do Commit desapareceram

Tags: git, eclipse

Estava trabalhando em um branch com Eclipse. Terminei as funcionalidades e fiz o commit, em seguida mudei para o branch master para fazer o push pro servidor. Mas quando fiz isso o commit desapareceu, tudo que tinha feito desapareceu. Fui no git repository e encontrei somente o arquivo COMMIT_EDITMSG com a mensagem do commit que eu fiz. Como recupero as alterações que eu tinha feito?

Comment: Você provavelmente fez o commit mas não fez o push, dê um checkout na branch que você estava trabalhando e verifique se os arquivos voltaram, caso tenham voltado você pode fazer o push ou então o merge com a branch master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O GIT quando você da o commit "armazena" o estado do seu workspace, o que imagino que tenha feito foi criar um branch, adicionar varios arquivos, trabalho no que precisava e deu commit certo?

Quando voltou para o branch master `git checkout master` o git reverte tudo para o estado do branch que você esta entrando, no caso master, que não tinha os arquivos que foram adicionados no outro branch.

Sugiro que leia a documentação do git [Ramificação (Branching) no Git - Básico de Branch e Merge](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ramifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Branching-no-Git-B%C3%A1sico-de-Branch-e-Merge)

Para ter no branch master o que foi feito no outro branch você precisa mesclar os dois branches, com `git merge`, seria algo como `git merge meubranch`.

Quando você usa o merge, superficialmente falando, o git analisa o que foi alterado, arquivos incluidos, removidos, e "mescla" com o seu branch, para que os dois fiquem no mesmo estado.

Um dos propósitos do git é justamente isso, você poder navegar entre os vários estados/commits, justamente para criar uma espécie de histórico de vida dos arquivos.

Não sei se consegui ser claro o suficiente.

Comment: Consegui recuperando o histórico dos repositórios.

Answer (score 1):

Suas alterações devem ter ficado na branch que voce estava trabalhando. Para ter essas alterações na master, deve realizar um merge entre as duas.